# searching a degenerate string in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am am trying to search for an exact pattern match to a degenerate or very slightly "fuzzy" string.

```
pattern = 'VGSGSGSGSAS' can be 10-50 characters long
string = "VGSGSGGSGSGSGSGSERGSAS" or "VGSGSGSGSGSGAGERSAS"  #it's actually 400 character long string 
string[11] = S|A
re.search(pattern, string) #does not work
```

so string[11] is either S or A. In this sample, I'm searching for the pattern in 2 defined strings, But, I don't want to make 2 separate strings, because there are actually multiple (at least 4) position in the 400 character string that have up to 3 different options each for a character. So I would be looking at making and searching in 24 different strings. And that's for just one sequence. Some of my sequences would turn into 64 different strings. Once I find the result of the search, I want to figure out where it starts and ends, and which string[11] character (S or A) it actually matches. Any ideas how I could do this pattern matching? Thank you!

Comment: So you want to center the pattern where it finds N or K at position 11 in the target string ? I.e. given the pattern is KVTMQNL

Comment: What do you mean by `where string[11] is either N or K` ?

Comment: I understand the strings differ by VGSE`KVTMQ[N|K]L`NDRLAS, but the _pattern_ to match that is `KVTMQ[N|K]L`. Therefore the _pattern_ is not fixed, it is variable.  The really strange part is you keep throwing in the _11th_ position in the _target_ string as if it has meaning. I see that at the 11th position in the target string marks the end of this variable pattern `KVTMQ[N|K]L`. That's the only relationship here, nothing else. Regex are very powerful if you understand them. Without any knowledge though, I can see why it would be hard to explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that, simple `str.find()` is enough to find it:

```
pattern = "KVTMQNL"  # substring to find
your_strings = ["VGSEKVTMQNLNDRLAS", "VGSEKVTMQKLNDRLAS"]  # just a list of strings
for source in your_strings:  # go through each string in our list
    print("String: {}\nEleventh character: {}".format(source, source[11]))
    if source[11] in ("N", "K"):  # check if it has `N` or `K` on its 11th position
        index = source.find(pattern)  # search for the pattern
        if index > -1:  # if the pattern is found anywhere in the string...
            print("Pattern start: {}\nPattern end: {}".format(index, index + len(pattern)))
        else:
            print("No match!")
    print("---")
```

Which will print out:

```
String: VGSEKVTMQNLNDRLAS
Eleventh character: N
Pattern start: 4
Pattern end: 11
---
String: VGSEKVTMQKLNDRLAS
Eleventh character: N
No match!
---
```

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, tho, your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: @user2789176 - the list above is to denote different strings as that's what your question implies. How else would you know what belongs to one and what belongs to another string?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if what i understood from your question is correct, you can use `re.search()` with a list of strings like this example:

```
import re

strings = ["VGSEKVTMQNLNDRLAS", "GSEKVTMQNLNDRLAS", "DRLASKVTMQKL", "GSEKVKVTMQPLDRLAS"]
pattern = r'KVTMQ[N|K]L'

for k in strings:
    s = re.search(pattern, k)
    print("Search in: {}  ".format(k), end = ' ')
    if s:
        print("Found: {} in position: {}".format(s.group(), s.span()))
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

Output:

```
Search in: VGSEKVTMQNLNDRLAS   Found: KVTMQNL in position: (4, 11)
Search in: GSEKVTMQNLNDRLAS   Found: KVTMQNL in position: (3, 10)
Search in: DRLASKVTMQKL   Found: KVTMQKL in position: (5, 12)
Search in: GSEKVKVTMQPLDRLAS   Not found
```